# QML module not found (QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0 )

Tags: qt, import, qml, cross-compiling, pi

I cross compiled Qt 5.14.1 for my Raspberry pi 4 on a Ubuntu 18.04,

for my application I need arcs when I searched I found out that arc belongs to `QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0` https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qml-qtquick-studio-components-arc.html

but when I added the `import QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0` in my `main.qml` I had an error `QML module not found (QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0 ) import paths : /opt/RaspberryQt/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/qml`

so in my `.pro` file I added
`QML_IMPORT_PATH = /opt/RaspberryQt/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/qml`

but I still have this error

these are the libraries that I installed on my Raspberry pi 4 before cross compiling. Can you please tell me which one is missing ?

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-qmake
sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5gui5
sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5webengine-data
sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5webkit5
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libinput-dev libts-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-xinerama0 gdbserver
```

and this is my configuration

```
cd /opt/RaspberryQt/build
../qt-everywhere-src-5.14.1/configure -release -opengl es2  -eglfs -device linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/RaspberryQt/tools/rpi-gcc-8.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /opt/RaspberryQt/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/RaspberryQt -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtscript -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -nomake tests -nomake examples -make libs -pkg-config -no-use-gold-linker -v -recheck
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem. First install Qt Design Studio (you can add components to the Qt installation by going to the Qt install directory, such as `C:\Qt` and running `MaintenanceTool.exe`.

Once installed, navigate to following path in the Qt install directory:

`[Wherever Installed]\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\bin\qml\QtQuick`

Then in there, copy the entire `Studio` folder, and paste it into:

`[Wherever Installed]\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qml\QtQuick`

Then relaunch Qt Creator and it should see it.

Note: There might be a more elegant way to import the modules from Qt Design Studio by adding the `[path]\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qml\` directory to the import paths, but that wasn't working for me, so I just did it with the method above.

Comment: `[Wherever Installed]\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\bin\qml\QtQuick` does not appear to be present in my installation

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the import from an extra qt module. So compile and install https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components.git;a=tree into the qt installation on your raoberry aswell.

Comment: I am sorry for my late replay. Thank you for helping. but I didn't understand exactly what should I do. I tried to download it with `wget https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components.git;a=blob;f=qtquickdesigner-components.pro;h=ce6617ea754f85f96a43fbfbaddfff1be0b6e468;hb=HEAD` and I just had a document. how to download these libraries? and should I download them in my raspberry before creating the sysroot and compiling Qt?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow-up to ThioJoe's answer:** 
If you've already tried [ThioJoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17312053/thiojoe)'s approach but facing the same issue, try this:

**1.** Copy the `Studio` folder located in: 
   `[Wherever Installed]\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\bin\qml\QtQuick`.

**2.** Paste the copied `Studio` folder into: 
  `[Wherever Installed]\Qt\6.2.3\mingw_64\qml\QtQuick` 
  (note, the *6.2.3* might
be different depending on your version).

**3.** Relaunch QtCreator.

Comment: This worked for me in the context of editing a QML file as text, the QML Designer plugin still fails! :(

Comment: I was able to force the plugin to find the QML source by exporting a `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` env var and then launching Creator, but once I had done this I found that the plugin version was not compatible...